# Common terminology for types of data validation?

Tags: terminology, validation

Are there any common terms for the difference between data validation you can do on, say, an object in and of itself, and validation that requires access to some sort of external resources?

For example, if I have a user record, I can check things like "Is username present?" "Is Username at least **n** characters long?" etc., without requiring any additional context. But as soon as I want to do something like "Is username available?" It requires checking against other records in my system.

I'm just wondering if there are any good terms for describing the difference in these types of scenarios? "Static analysis" vs. "run-time checking" sort of fits, but it's clearly not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know of any widely accepted terms for these different kinds of validation. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation) provides you some guidance.

What's important is that you define/use a set of terms that everyone in your team agrees with and uses. I believe that the terms you're proposing (*static* vs *runtime*) are not good because all these rules are exercised at *runtime* anyway. I would propose something like *intrinsic* vs *extrinsic* or *internal* vs *external* validation.